# Problems with detecting collision for a character selection screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a character selection screen similar to that of something like Super Smash Bros. and using a controller, but I'm having trouble doing so. Currently this is what I have for to try to accomplish this

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Joystick1Button1))
    {
        RaycastHit rayInfo;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(transform.position);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayInfo))
        {
            Debug.Log("raycast hit");
            rayInfo.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("Selected");
        }
    }
```

But from what I can tell it doesn't seem to me like the ray cast is hitting anything due to the fact that the debug.log never runs despite being directly over the icon/character I would like to select. How can I fix this and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the screen point that you're using to do the ray collision is `transform.position`. Unless this script is attached to a game object that already follows the mouse somehow, you probably want that to be the mouse position.

Secondly, you should check to make sure that there is a collider on the object that you're trying to raycast into.

Thirdly, if the selection screen is 2d, you can get away with:

```
Collider2D hitInfo =Physics2D.OverlapPoint(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
if (hitInfo.gameObject!=null){
//Do selection logic here.
}
```

Comment: I do have this scripts attached to a cursor object as i am doing this in regards to a controller rather than a mouse. I have also attempted to use this code testing with both the mouse and the controller but I find that it does not work with the controllers pointer and the transform.position. I simply get the null reference error that occurs when you click over nothing even when using mouse